# Entity framework pre-generating views

Tags: entity-framework

I am pre-generating views for the entity data model in my project; following the instruction given by MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx

I have completed the changes without any problem. I can now see CSDL, SSDL and MSL files added to my project. Does this mean I will have to update these files everytime I update my entity data model? If so, its quite a bit of overhead since our database changes quite frequently.

Is there a better way to update these files everytime I update the edmx?

Thanks

Comment: Are you not seeing them update for you when you build? Once added to your project/solution, the files will still be updated on your build event.  But like much of the tooling in VS, if you don't build your project the updated namespaces/types/fields won't be available to IntelliSense, if that's what you're going after.

Comment: I see that the View file is updated on each build. However the CSDL/SSDL/MSDL files are placed in the bin directory. The instructions ask to add these files to the project. Hence they get copied to the project. So they do not get updated everytime I rebuild. I can add a link to files in the bin, instead of copying the files to the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what we do in our project:

- Open the EDMX and right click the surface-> Properties.
- Set Metadata Artifcat Processing to "Copy to Output Directory"
- Add the resulting /bin/debug/ .csdl .msl and .ssdl to your project (show all files in solution explorer and right click, Include in Project)
- Next set the .csdl .msl and .ssdl properties to be embedded resource.
- Build and reference the files in the entity framework connection string in your runtime project.

Comment: If you have trouble at runtime then you can use our connection string style :<add name="Ent" connectionString="metadata=res://DAL/DAL.bin.Debug.DataModel.csdl|res://DAL/DAL.bin.Debug.DataModel.ssdl|res://DAL/DAL.bin.Debug.DataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=YOURSERVERANDINSTANCE;Initial Catalog=YOURDB;uid=YOURUSER;pwd=YOURPWD;Integrated Security=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: I'm sure that there's a simpler naming mechanism than this but after trying a few we got this one up and running and also explicitly naming the res:// rather than res://* gives quite a performance increase.

Comment: Thanks Rick. Thats what I have done. But if you add CSDL/MSL/SSDL files from bin\debug, everytime you rebuild the EDMX, you will have to manually add these files again. This is what I want to avoid.

Comment: We don't manually add them each time. It's included in the project and you'll have a reference to that project from your other one so when you rebuild you should get the new DLL containing the embedded resources in it in the bin folder of your referring project no?